# C# Selenium Chrome SendKeys skips ^°`´

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, sendkeys

I have an issue with C# Selenium Chrome SendKeys. I wanted to send :
^°`´

But all of these characters don't show up in the input.
Do you have any idea how to solve it?

Edit:
The issue is depending on the keyboard layout. It works with English keyboard layout but not with German layout. But I can enter the values into the input field.

Thanks
Nico

Comment: Update the question with the relevant text based HTML and your code trials.

Comment: What character set is the web page using? Typically this is declared in the `<meta charset="X">` tag inside the `<head>` of the HTML document.

Comment: We have <meta charset="utf-8">